# Bracket highlighter for commented code in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, vscode-extensions

Trying to find a way to highlight parentheses for commented code. I have been using ***Bracket Pair Colorizer 2*** in VScode and don't see an option for it. Please refer line #20 in the below screenshot for more clarity. [image]

Comment: highlight `brackets` you mean?

Comment: That's right, Mark.

Comment: Look tat https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight  Highlight

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, but it doesn't highlight the bracket in commented code.

Comment: It'll match and color anything that can be matched with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this setting with the [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) extension:

```
 "highlight.regexes": {
    "(.*//[^[]*?)(\\[)([^\\]]*?)(])": [
      {}, 
      { "color": "white" },
      {},
      { "color": "white" }
    ]
  },
```

or

```
  "highlight.regexes": {
  
    "(.*//[^\\[]+?)(\\[)([^\\]]+?)(\\])(.*)": {
      "filterLanguageRegex": "javascript",
      "decorations": [
        {}, 
        { "color": "white" },
        {},
        { "color": "white" },
        {}
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: why do you need to escape the `/`?

Comment: @rioV8 Apparently you don't.  Thanks I updated the answer.  Got escape-happy.  Still worked though.